# compile certain files in a directory with special compilation flags

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make, compiler-optimization

I have several files in the project directory, I want to compile certain files with very specific compilation options and the other files with standard compilation options, I want to use if else to process the files.

problem that I currently have, the program crashes on if statement, could you help me please?

For Information, i use windows cmd.exe

below the expected results and thank you very much for your help

Makefile :

```
SPECIAL_FILES := Fee_PBcfg.obj Fee.obj Can_17_McmCan_PBcfg.obj Dio.obj 
Dio_Lcfg.obj Mcu.obj  Can_17_McmCan_Isr.obj Can_17_McmCan.obj 
McalLib.obj  Spi_PBcfg.obj Spi.obj EcuM_Callout_Stubs.obj EcuM_Cfg.obj 
EcuM_Init_Cfg.obj 



%.$(OBJ_EXT): %.c $(MCS_H)_mcs.h $(COMPILER_OPT_FILE)
if exist $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.obj del $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.obj
if exist $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.d del $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.d
if exist $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.i del $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.i
if exist $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.s del $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.s
if $(filter $*, $(SPECIAL_FILES))
    $(DBGOUT)
    echo Compile $* with $(COPT_ECHO_MCAL) option
    $(CC) $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS_MCAL) $(INCLUDES_PATH) -o 
$(BUILD_PATH)/$*.obj $< 2>$(BUILD_PATH)/$*.warn || type 
$(BUILD_PATH)\$*.warn && $(FALSE)
else
    $(DBGOUT)
    echo Compile $* with $(COPT_ECHO) option
    $(CC) $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES_PATH) -o $(BUILD_PATH)/$*.obj 
$< 2>$(BUILD_PATH)/$*.warn || type $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.warn && $(FALSE)
endif
```

[image: The Expected result]

Comment: Hi; please edit your question to ensure the formatting of the text is correct, and also please don't insert images into programming questions; instead cut and paste text with formatting.  Thanks!

Comment: In makefiles, indentation is critical but in your examples the indentation is missing or not clear.

Comment: *indentation is critical* and more precisely the use of TABs for commands, for which [Stuart Feldman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_Feldman), the creator of the original Unix make command, keeps apologizing about.  I met him once 40 years ago at Bell Labs: the first thing he told me after a colleague of mine had introduced him as the inventor of make was "*Yes... Sorry for the TABs*".

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `ifeq` etc. because these are like preprocessor statements: they are processed when the makefile is read in.  But, recipes are not constructed until much later when make is going to build the target.

In the GNU Make manual you'll find that automatic variables like `$*` are only valid inside the recipe; by "inside the recipe" here they mean within the recipe script, which is the portion of the rule indented by TAB characters and passed to the shell.  Make operators like `ifeq` etc. are (as above) make preprocessor statements and are not part of the recipe.

To satisfy your requirements you can make use of [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).  Something like this:

```
$(SPECIAL_FILES) : CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS_MCAL)

%.$(OBJ_EXT): %.c $(MCS_H)_mcs.h $(COMPILER_OPT_FILE)
        ...
        echo Compile $* with $(CFLAGS) option
        $(CC) $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES_PATH) -o $(BUILD_PATH)/$*.obj $< 2>$(BUILD_PATH)/$*.warn || type $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.warn && $(FALSE)
```

Or if you prefer, you can keep most of the CFLAGS the same and just add some extra ones for the special targets:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS =
$(SPECIAL_FILES) : EXTRA_CFLAGS := $(MCAL_FLAGS)

%.$(OBJ_EXT): %.c $(MCS_H)_mcs.h $(COMPILER_OPT_FILE)
        ...
        echo Compile $* with $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) option
        $(CC) $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES_PATH) -o $(BUILD_PATH)/$*.obj $< 2>$(BUILD_PATH)/$*.warn || type $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.warn && $(FALSE)
```

**ETA**

Note that each line of the recipe is invoked in a separate shell.  So you can't create statements that span multiple lines; for example:

```
        if $(filter $*, $(SPECIAL_FILES))
           $(DBGOUT)
           echo Compile $* with $(COPT_ECHO_MCAL) option
           $(CC) $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS_MCAL) $(INCLUDES_PATH) -o $(BUILD_PATH)/$*.obj $< 2>$(BUILD_PATH)/$*.warn || type $(BUILD_PATH)\$*.warn && $(FALSE)
```

is an error because only the first line (the `if` statement) is passed to the shell, which is not valid syntax.

If you were using a POSIX shell, which has good support for writing complex scripts all on the same line (you add `;` between statements and it has a regular syntax) this is quite possible.

My suspicion is that if you are writing your makefiles using the baroque Windows cmd shell, you won't have much success doing it this way since it is very difficult to write long batch commands without using newlines.  But, if you want to do this you will need to ask this question of people who know a lot about the intricacies of Windows batch files: it's not really a make issue.

One thing you can try is adding the [`.ONESHELL:` pseudo-target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) to your makefile which tells make to run the entire recipe in a single shell.  Maybe that will help.

My recommendation would be to avoid all this and instead use GNU Make features to restrict these complexities to your makefile, rather than trying to run them in the shell that make invokes.